# Positioning Shiny widgets beside their headers

Tags: r, shiny

How can I position Shiny widgets (e.g. the dropdown box of `selectInput()`) besides their headers?  I've been playing around with various `tags` formulations without any luck.  Grateful for any pointers.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)  
pageWithSidebar( 
  headerPanel("side-by-side"), 
  sidebarPanel(
tags$head(
  tags$style(type="text/css", ".control-label {display: inline-block;}"),
  tags$style(type="text/css", "#options { display: inline-block; }"),
  tags$style(type="text/css", "select { display: inline-block; }")
),
selectInput(inputId = "options", label = "dropdown dox:", 
  choices = list(a = 0, b = 1))
  ),
  mainPanel( 
    h3("bla bla")
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) { NULL })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(shiny)  

runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar( 
  headerPanel("side-by-side"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", "label.control-label, .selectize-control.single{ display: inline-block!important; }")
    ),
    selectInput(inputId = "options", label = "dropdown dox:", 
                choices = list(a = 0, b = 1))
  ),
  mainPanel( 
    h3("bla bla")
  )
)
, server = function(input, output) { NULL })
)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly, thanks!  How would I refer to element by id?  If I use `#options` instead I strangely get 2 dropdown boxes.

Comment: More generally, how did you get to `.selectize-control.single`?  I can't find reference to this.  thanks again

Comment: The `id='option'` element is not visible so we don't target it. The two visible components of the selectize control are the label and the selector itself. `.selectize-control.single` is equivalent to `class = "selectize-control single"` so it targets an element with those two classes.

Comment: This is a bit confusing considering `selectize-control single ` relates to a select/option element.  The [shiny docs](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html) don't detail how shiny elements relate to selectize.  Nothing obvious in [selectize reference](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/tree/master/docs) either.  Do you know if this is detailed anywhere?

Comment: The `selectInput` in shiny is actually a `selectize` input by default. To use the old `selectInput` you need to use the `selectize = FALSE` argument in `selectInput`. See the details section of `?selectInput`.

Comment: `sliderInput` is not a selectize element so how do I handle that?! :)

Comment: If `sliderInput` is not a selectize element applying the css to the label element alone should be sufficient.

Comment: Ah ok `.control-label` and `.jslider-single` works. Thanks again John