# Shiny 1.0.5 make sliderInput inline with label

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to make several sliders where the label is on the left slide of the slider rather than on top of it.

I saw these two solutions:

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1737

[Label next to selectInput in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960035/label-next-to-selectinput-in-shiny/33960430#33960430)

However they do not seem to work with new shiny template. The labels and slider do indeed become inline, but the size of slider really shrinks.

If I manually set .irs-line width to a specific number of pixels, I do get a proper size slider, but it looks horrible on different screens or if the window is minimized. And if I try making it "auto" or "100%", I am back to a "dot" instead of slider.

Reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    width = 4,
    div(HTML("<b>Bla bla bla bla bla</b>")),
    br(),
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", 
                 "label.control-label, .selectize-control.single { 
                 display: table-cell; 
                 text-align: center; 
                 vertical-align: middle; 
                 } 
                 label.control-label {
                 padding-right: 10px;
                 }
                 .form-group { 
                 display: table-row;
                 }
                 .selectize-control.single div.item {
                 padding-right: 15px;
                 }
                 .irs-line{
                 width: 100%;
                 }")
    ),
    sliderInput("lbl1", "label 1", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl2", "label 2", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl3", "label 3", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl4", "long label number 4", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl5", "label 5", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl6", "label 6", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl7", "label 7", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl8", "label 8", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl9", "label 9", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1)
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: "The labels and slider do indeed become inline, but the size of slider really shrinks" I can't really see the difference in size with and without the CSS. Can you add a small screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: I updated the desciption. in the code I wrote initially, i put the `width:300px` but if you change it `width:100%` or `width:auto`, it turns into what is shown on the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I will share what I know:

You can always use relative sizes to configure your widgets on the div. 
Use for example `width:10vw` (vw refer to your screen width) and `height:10vh` (vh refer to your screen height).

I applied this and modified your code a bit, seems to work for me.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    div(style="width:10vw;",

    width = 4,
    div(HTML("<b>Bla bla bla bla bla</b>")),
    br(),
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", 
                 "label.control-label, .selectize-control.single { 

                 text-align: center; 
                 vertical-align: middle; 
                 } 
                 label.control-label {
                 padding-right: 20vw;
                 }
                 .form-group { 
                 display: table-row;
                 }
                 .selectize-control.single div.item {
                 padding-right: 20vw;
                 }
")
    ),
    sliderInput("lbl1", "label 1", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl2", "label 2", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl3", "label 3", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl4", "long label number 4", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl5", "label 5", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl6", "label 6", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl7", "label 7", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl8", "label 8", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1),
    sliderInput("lbl9", "label 9", min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, step = 1)
      )
    ))
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```