# R, Shiny : Inline selectInput

Tags: css, r, widget, position, shiny

1 ) How can we position a `selectInput` next to an other one? I tried :

```
# style.css
.general {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: auto;
width : auto ;
white-space: nowrap ;}

# ui.R
...
tags$div(class = "general", selectInput(...), selectInput(...))
...
```

but it doesn't work.

2) How can we position the label of a `selectInput` next to the `selectInput` itself ? I found this topic [Positioning Shiny widgets beside their headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249128/positioning-shiny-widgets-beside-their-headers)
but this is designed for all the `selectInput` of the app. I did not managed to use the code provided in `tags$style(...)` for only one `selectInput` of my app, not all of them. How can we do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself for question 1), with a simple example :

```
# style.css
.divleft {
  float : left;
  width : 50%;
}

.clearl {
  clear: left;
}

# ui.R
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tagList(
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css",href="style.css")
    )
  ),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("s1", "Select 1", 1:10),
        tags$div(
          tags$div(class = "divleft", selectInput("s2", label = "Select 2", 1:5, width = validateCssUnit("70%"))),
          tags$div(class = "divleft", selectInput("s3", label = "Select 3", 1:5, width = validateCssUnit("70%")))
        ),
        tags$div(class = "clearl",
                selectInput("s4", "Select 4", 1:5)
                 )
        , width = 3),
      mainPanel(
        h3("Example")
      )
    )
  )
)

# server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { })
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try using one fluid row and several columns. Since the total fluid row width = 12 you may put up to 12 columns one after another without any additional css.  For example:

```
fluidRow(
column(6, selectInput("S1", label = "S1")),
column(6, selectInput("S2", label = "S2"))
)
```