# Shiny Dashboard horizontal input labels

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am currently developing a shiny dashboard app where screen realestate is at a premium. I've adjusted the custom css based on guidance from [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#css) and am attempting to put input labels beside the input object (rather than the default of above). I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249128/positioning-shiny-widgets-beside-their-headers), however after trying it in my dashboard application it does not work.

I've tried a few different hacks but to no avail. Unfortunately I am not a front end dev, and even with trying to replicate examples from the AdminLTE website I haven't had any success.

Reprex using the code from the other question but in a shiny dashboard.

```
# reprex

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "mytitle in here")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar("some stuff")

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(type="text/css", "label.control-label, .selectize-control.single{ display: inline-block!important; }")
  ),
  box(width = 12,
    column(2, 
           selectInput(inputId = "input1", label = "input #1", 
                       choices = letters[1:4],  multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE),
           selectInput(inputId = "input2", label = "input #2", 
                       choices = letters[10:14], multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE)
           ),
    column(2,
           selectInput(inputId = "input3", label = "input #3", choices = c(2000:2004), selectize = TRUE),
           selectInput(inputId = "input4", label = "input #4", 
                       choices = letters[26:20], multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE))
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, title = "my dashboard")

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) { NULL })

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Using the `tag$style()` from my comment renders the inputs to look like this where the input selections are don't then fill the rest of the column width.
[image]

**DESIRED OUTCOME**
What I am hoping to be able to achieve is to have inputs that look like this (consistent width) while having the labels beside, rather than above.

[image]

Comment: I just tried the answer with `shiny 1.0.0` and it worked fine. The sizing of the boxes is terrible, but it does put the labels beside the input.

Comment: It doesn't work on my setup with shiny 1.0.0 and R 3.3.2 on Win 7... Can't help, sorry

Comment: @HubertL I did also see this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960035/label-next-to-selectinput-in-shiny) and it works on my windows system (similar to your environment) although if I recall correctly when I tried it the input boxes shrink dramatically.

Comment: That one does work on my system, but as you noticed the result is not great

Comment: does it work on your dashboard when you use that one tag$style?

Comment: On my mac the question in the most works similar to the outcomes from the Q&A in the comments. I've edited the question to show what things look like with the results of the`tag$style()` from the Q&A in the comments.

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue, please clarify what you are expecting