# Place shiny widget header in the same line with the input in shiny app

Tags: css, r, shiny

Im trying to put the header of the shiny widget next to it like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249128/positioning-shiny-widgets-beside-their-headers) but unfortunatelly it does not work and see no change. Anybody else facing the same issue?

```
library(shiny)  

runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar( 
  headerPanel("side-by-side"), 
  sidebarPanel(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(type="text/css", "label.control-label, .selectize-control.single{ display: inline-block!important; }")
    ),
    selectInput(inputId = "options", label = "dropdown dox:", 
                choices = list(a = 0, b = 1))
  ),
  mainPanel( 
    h3("bla bla")
  )
)
, server = function(input, output) { NULL })
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is not working.  You can adjust the CSS to make it work. However, you need to play with the numbers (font size, width, etc) as required in your case.  Try this

```
library(shiny)

css <- 
  "
.container {
margin: 20px;
padding: 15px;
}
#expr-container .selectize-input {
  font-size: 44px;
line-height: 44px;
width: 300px;
}
#expr-container .selectize-dropdown {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 22px;
}
#expr-container .selectize-dropdown-content {
max-height: 225px;
padding: 0;
}
#expr-container .selectize-dropdown-content .option {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
#expr-container label{ 
display: table-cell; 
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: middle;  
}
#expr-container .form-group { 
display: table-row; 
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("side-by-side"),
  sidebarPanel(
    tags$style(css),
    fluidRow(
      
      tags$div(id = "expr-container", selectInput(inputId = "options", label = "Select Me: ", 
                                          choices = list(aaaaaa = 0, bbbbbb = 1), 
                                          multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE #, width = "60%"
                                          ) )
      
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h3("bla bla")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

**EDIT**:  add color

```
#expr-container .selectize-input {
  font-size: 44px;
line-height: 44px;
color: blue;
border-color: red;
width: 300px;
}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: where should I put border-color: red; to make border colors red?

Comment: maybe you could help with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65522907/change-borders-color-length-and-distance-from-label-in-a-shiny-widget-using-cs