# Change borders' color, length and distance from label in a shiny widget using css

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have the shiny app below in which I use `css` to change the borders' color of the `shiny` widget to red and also change the length of the input and its distance from its label `"Name"`. But despite some of the parameters I have given in `css` part work, those mentioned above do not. Here is what needs to be done.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

css <- 
  "
.container {
margin: 20px;
padding: 15px;
}
#expr-container .selectize-input {
  font-size: 44px;
line-height: 44px;
color: blue;
border-color: red;
width: 300px;
}
#expr-container .selectize-dropdown {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 22px;
}
#expr-container .selectize-dropdown-content {
max-height: 5px;
padding: 0;
}
#expr-container .selectize-dropdown-content .option {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
#expr-container label{ 
display: table-cell; 
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: middle;  
}
#expr-container .form-group { 
display: table-row; 
}
"
mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent",style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6"))
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
  
  
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
      
      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      
      
      tabItems(
        tabItem("conse",
                
                  fluidRow(column(1,),column(3,
                                             
                                             tags$style(css),
                                             tags$div(id = "expr-container",textInput("name", label = ("Name"), value = ""))))
                 
                )
       
      )
      
    )
    
  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")
    
  
  }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
css <-
"
#expr-container .form-control {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid black;
  color: blue;
}
"

mytitle <- paste0("Life, Death & Statins")
dbHeader <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  titleWidth = "0px",
  tags$li(a(
    div(style="display: inline;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;vertical-align:top; width: 150px;", actionButton("conse", "Consent",style=" background-color: #faf0e6; border-color: #faf0e6"))
  ),
  class = "dropdown")
)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dbHeader,
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(width = "0px",
                               sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar", # id important for updateTabItems
                                           menuItem("Consent", tabName = "conse", icon = icon("line-chart"))
                               )           ),
    body = dashboardBody(
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),

      tags$head(tags$style(".skin-blue .main-header .logo { padding: 0px;}")),
      


      tabItems(
        tabItem("conse",

                fluidRow(column(2,paste("Name: ")), 
                         #column(1,), 
                         column(5, #textInput("name", label = NULL, value = "", width="100%")
                                tags$style(css),
                                tags$div(id = "expr-container", textInput("name", label = NULL, value = "", width="100%") ) 
                                ))

        )

      )

    )

  ),
  server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    hide(selector = "body > div > header > nav > a")


  }
  )
)
```

[image: output]

Comment: If you don't want to mess with shinys default CSS you can just leave the label empty and create a label next to it instead of forcing the existing label to the side and adjusting the space.

Comment: Thanks but how can I make the borders color black and change the length of input as well?

Comment: Also the more I increase the 150px to the right the smaller the input length is getting.

Comment: ok you used the label-out solution. the only issue here is that the text seems a little bit higher that the center of the input

Comment: In that case, you can include the previous CSS code and it should work.  Please play with it by modifying or adding one item at a time.