# In R shiny, How to align text and icon in radio button on the same line？

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

When I use R shany, [image]I want to align the text and icon to left side in one radio button on the same line. However, when I use the CSS change the text to left side, the icon not move. I also want the icon in left side too. Here are some codes.

```
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    ".first-p {text-align: left;}
    "
  ),

  radioGroupButtons(
    inputId = "Id067",
    label = "Label",
    choiceNames = list( p(class = "first-p", "Yes (Start the survey)"),
                        p(class = "first-p", "No (End the survey)")
                        ),
    choiceValues = list("yes", "no"),
    
    direction = "vertical",
    selected = character(0),
    width   = "100%",
    status = 'success',
    size = 'normal',
    checkIcon = list(
      yes = icon("ok", 
                 lib = "glyphicon")
      
    )),
  
  
  )

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place shiny widget header in the same line with the input in shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495433/place-shiny-widget-header-in-the-same-line-with-the-input-in-shiny-app)

Comment: Thank you for the comment@Limey. However, this answer is too complicated for me, I didn't find what I need.

Comment: Try `direction = "horizontal"`.